# QML DefaultProperty for ObjectList/Repeater

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I'm extending QML with my own widget from c++, with `DefaultProperty` and `QQmlListProperty`, like [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-referenceexamples-default-example.html).

So that I can write

```
Parent {    
    Child { prop: "ch1" }
    Child { prop: "ch2" }
    Child { prop: "ch3" }
}
```

The Child objects are appending to a member property of type [QQmlListProperty](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmllistproperty.html).

But when I want to use a [Repeater](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-repeater.html) like this:

```
Parent {
    Repeater {
        model: ["ch1","ch2","ch3"]
        delegate: Child {
            prop: modelData
        }
    }
}
```

Then the runtime gives me an error: `Cannot assign object to list property "childObjects"`

How can I set the list property of my Parent object which a Repeater?

EDIT: I've found out, that the `Repeater` inherits `Item` and can repeat only Items. But my `Child` object inherits `QObject`. So I must create a `Repeater` for `QObjects`. But that isn't the problem. How can the `Item` object have a manually written child items, and also a Repeater child which gives him many children?

Comment: You're right, `Repeater` used for visual items only. But you can create `Child` objects with `Qt.createComponent()` in loop. Or implement such functionality as `Repeater` with C++ extension.

Comment: @folibis you're right, but creating my own repeater is difficult, if not impossible. I'm looking in qt code, and the `Repeater` class has so many private members, and uses classes that are not publicly available ...

Comment: Ok, then use `Qt.createComponent()` in loop. All you need, as I understand is creating a component and assigning it to `Parent`.

Answer (score 0):

### Use a QObjectList Model

You say your `Child` are QObjects, then you can use a [QObjectList](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html#qobjectlist-based-model) instead of your construct. Expose the list with something similar to:

```
class Parent : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QList<QObject*> elements READ ...  WRITE ... NOTIFY ...)
}

class Child : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString something READ ...  WRITE ... NOTIFY ...)
    Q_PROPERTY(int     myValue   READ ...  WRITE ... NOTIFY ...)
    ...
}
```

Then you use the `elements` property of `Parent` as a model for the repeater, it will have access to all of the properties (Q_PROPERTIES) of the Child elements.

```
Parent {
    id: main
}
Repeater {
    model: main.elements
    delegate: Whatever { // will create one for each element
        prop: something
        prop2: myValue
    }
 }
```